# Best way to compare Periods in using NodaTime (or alternative)

Tags: c#, nodatime

I have a requirement to have a relative min/max date validation able to be stored in a database to customize an application per customer.  I decided that the `NodaTime.Period` due to it's capability to specify years was the best choice.  However, `NodaTime.Period` does not offer a way to compare itself against another period.

Example data provided for this validation:

- Minimum Age of 18 years old.
- Maximum Age o 100 years old.
- Minimum sale duration of 1 month
- Maximum sale duration of 3 months
- Minimum advertising campaign 7 days

(Note: Current requirements are that Year / Month / Day will not be combined in validations)

The validations are:

```
public Period RelativeMinimum { get; set; }
public Period RelativeMaximum { get; set; }
```

Given a user entered date (and now):

```
var now = new LocalDate(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
var userValue = new LocalDate(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day);
var difference = Period.Between(userValue, now);
```

I have a comparison of:

```
if(RelativeMinimum != null && difference.IsLessThan(RelativeMinimum))))
{
    response.IsValid = false;
    response.Errors.Add(MinimumErrorMessage);
}
```

Which is consuming an extensions class:

```
public static class PeriodExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLessThan(this Period p, Period p2)
    {
        return (p.Years < p2.Years) || (p.Years == p2.Years && p.Months < p2.Months) || (p.Years == p2.Years && p.Months == p2.Months && p.Days < p2.Days);
    }

    public static bool IsGreaterThan(this Period p, Period p2)
    {
        return (p.Years > p2.Years) || (p.Years == p2.Years && p.Months > p2.Months) || (p.Years == p2.Years && p.Months == p2.Months && p.Days > p2.Days);
    }
}
```

While this approach works, given the test conditions I have, I have to wonder why @jon-skeet didn't implement this, and immediately have to worry over what am I missing and what alternative should I be using instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason periods aren't comparable is that they can contain components of variable lengths.

Two one-month periods aren't necessarily the same number of days long.  As an example, which is greater: 1 month or 30 days?  If the month is January, then that's longer than 30 days.  If the month is February, that's less than 30 days.

The same applies to years.  Some are 365 days long, some are 366.

Of course, that all assumes you're using the Gregorian calendar.  Noda Time supports other calendar systems, and there are similar quirks in those as well.

Regarding the code:

- If you want a `LocalDate` from a `DateTime`, use `LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dt).Date`
- To get the current date, use `SystemClock.Instance.Now.InZone(tz).Date`

  - If you intended that to be the same as `DateTime.Now`, which uses the local time zone of the computer where the code is running, then get `tz` by calling `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault()`
- For comparison of the type of problem you have described, consider defining min and max *days* instead of min and max *periods*.  Then you wont have such variation of units.  You can get the difference in days like this:

  ```
  long days = Period.Between(d1, d2, PeriodUnits.Days).Days;
  ```

I believe something like this would work well for your use case:

```
public static bool IsDifferenceLessThan(LocalDate d1, LocalDate d2, Period p)
{
    if (p.HasTimeComponent)
        throw new ArgumentException("Can only compare dates.", "p");

    if (p.Years != 0)
    {
        if (p.Months != 0 || p.Weeks != 0 || p.Days != 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Can only compare one component of a period.", "p");

        var years = Period.Between(d1, d2, PeriodUnits.Years).Years;
        return years < p.Years;
    }

    if (p.Months != 0)
    {
        if (p.Weeks != 0 || p.Days != 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Can only compare one component of a period.", "p");

        var months = Period.Between(d1, d2, PeriodUnits.Months).Months;
        return months < p.Months;
    }

    if (p.Weeks != 0)
    {
        if (p.Days != 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Can only compare one component of a period.", "p");

        var weeks = Period.Between(d1, d2, PeriodUnits.Weeks).Weeks;
        return weeks < p.Weeks;
    }

    var days = Period.Between(d1, d2, PeriodUnits.Days).Days;
    return days < p.Days;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the customer requirement is to be able to say things like: minimum of 13 years old, minimum sale duration of 1 month, or campaign duration of 2 days...  I'll update my question to account for this.  The day only comparison unfortunately won't work, but the post was still very informative!

Comment: You can still use the approach I described in the last bullet.  You would just need to vary the period units based on the validation you were trying to do.  For example, `...PeriodUnits.Months).Months` or `...PeriodUnits.Years).Years`.

Comment: So if I wrote a way to check what the period unit was by saying Year != 0 -> Year or Month != 0 -> Month... etc.  Would that suffice? (Based on the RelativeMinimum or RelativeMaximum)

Comment: Essentially, yes.  See the update I posted.  I think you can extrapolate the other methods from there.  The key part is that the `Between` operation is told what type of calendrical component you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Matt!  Perfect insight I needed on this :-)  Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Just as an additional point to Matt's already-excellent answer, we provide an option for creating an `IComparer<Period>` with a specific anchor point, e.g.

```
var febComparer = Period.CreateComparer(new LocalDate(2015, 2, 1).AtMidnight());
var marchComparer = Period.CreateComparer(new LocalDate(2015, 3, 1).AtMidnight());
var oneMonth = Period.FromMonths(1);
var twentyNineDays = Period.FromDays(29);

// -1: Feb 1st + 1 month is earlier than Feb 1st + 29 days
Console.WriteLine(febComparer.Compare(oneMonth, twentyNineDays));
// 1: March 1st + 1 month is later than March 1st + 29 days
Console.WriteLine(marchComparer.Compare(oneMonth, twentyNineDays));
```

Comment: I had been looking at the `Comparer` and didn't think it could really solve what I was after.  However, it's nice to actually understand what / how the `CreateComparer` works, this might provide another alternative approach.  (RTFM I know... Thank you @jon-skeet!!)

Comment: @VulgarBinary: Yup - I added this answer basically for others... I don't think it's the right solution to your use case, but *may* be the right solution for others who want to compare periods in a simple way.

Comment: Yep!  The API docs on the nodatime.org site didn't completely click for me, but this did. I'm sure others looking around will find this immensely helpful.  :-)

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know about this particular tidbit. :)